# VB to C# how to convert if param and 1

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm converting some VB code in C#, i have this if sentence

```
if param and 1 then
...
end if
```

i don't get how to convert this in C# (btw param is a short), is this something related to power of 2? How can i convert this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write this as a boolean expression:

```
if ((param & 1) != 0)
{
    ..
}
```

Comment: That worked well, thank you Lasse! (asap i'll accept it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a code convert to migrate you code across try the following site:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: for this exact scenario, the converter converts wrong.

Comment: Nice link, but that tool convert it like if (param & 1) {}

Comment: The Telerik converter uses NRefactory, and produces incorrect code in lots of small cases. To be blunt, in those cases where it produces the wrong code is probably those cases where it is unlikely that you will detect the problem yourself, considering that there is a reason you're not doing the code conversion by hand. My advice: Don't use the Telerik code converter other than for illustration purposes.